# Aggregate high resolution (300m*300m) raster (raster::aggregate and velox not able to handle well this resolution)

Tags: r, bigdata, aggregate, r-raster, velox

I'm trying to aggregate a raster r of global extent from a ~300m*300m (10 arc‐seconds, 7.4GB) resolution to a ~10km resolution (0.083333 decimal degrees), i.e. a factor of 30.
Both the aggregate functions from the raster and the velox packages do not seem to handle such large dataset. I very much welcome recommendations!

```
# sample rasters
r <- raster(extent(-180,180, -90 , 90))
res(r)<-c(0.5/6/30, 0.5/6/30)
r <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r))) # Error: cannot allocate vector of size 62.6 Gb

# velox example
devtools::install_github('hunzikp/velox')
library(velox)
vx <- velox(r) # the process aborts in linux
vx$aggregate(factor=30, aggtype='mean')

# raster example
r_agg <- aggregate(r, fact=30)
```

Comment: Please include sample data and code you have tried to enable solutions to be verified.

Comment: R is a bit of a resource hog, since it keeps files in memory. I would recommend just using direct GDAL tools (gdalwarp or gdal_translate - if you just want to aggregate you can use the later). You can call them as system command from within R (or via CLI or QGIS). At its most basic, it'll be something like `gdal_translate -tr 0.08333 0.08333 -r average source_file destination_file`, where -tr is your inteneded output resolution,  and -r is your aggregating method.

Comment: @scabecks thanks a lot for the suggestion. It seems to be working great! I borrowed a linux box for this, but my main system is Windows. Do you know of a way to perform this trick on a Windows machine?

Comment: GDAL installs and works on windows perfectly fine as well. I think the only issue is getting things to run multithreaded on windows (which can be a big time savings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that `raster` cannot handle a large raster like that, but that is not true. The problem is that you are trying to create a very large data set in memory --- more memory than your computer has available. You can use the `init` function instead. I show that below but not using a global 300 m raster to make the example run a bit faster.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ymn=80, res=0.5/6/30)
r <- init(r, "col")
r_agg <- aggregate(r, fact=30)
```

You get better mileage with `terra`

```
library(terra)
rr <- rast(ymin=80, res= 0.5/6/30)
rr <- init(rr, "col")
rr_agg <- aggregate(rr, fact=30)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Robert's suggestion, I'd resample the rast with a template so the ext and crs would be precise.

> r <- terra::rast("your_rast.tif") %>%

> aggregate(., fact = 30)  %>%

> resample(., template_rast, filename ="sth.tif",
> wopt = list(gdal = c("COMPRESS=LZW", "TFW=YES", "BIGTIFF=YES"),
> tempdir = "somewhere_you_have_a_lot_of_space", todisk = TRUE))

Those wopt options might help you a lot with large rasters.